# How to get Microsoft.Extensions.Logging<T> in console application using Serilog and AutoFac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac, serilog

We have common BL classes in a ASP.NET Core application that get in the ctor:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<Foo>`

In ASP.NET Core, the internal infrastructure of ASP.NET handles getting the ILogger via the `LoggerFactory`.

We now want to reuse these BL classes in a console application (for async jobs), how do we setup *AutoFac* and Serilog to inject `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` in environment that `LoggerFactory` doesn't exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "Environment that LoggerFactory doesn't exist"? LoggerFactory is not part of ASP.NET Core its part of the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package, see https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggerFactory.cs

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` (see [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggerFactory.cs)) is not part of ASP.NET Core and can run independently of it. All you need to do is to register the `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger<>` interface.

The `ILoggerFactory` [is used by](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a057f27e860c1a59aa12e7dd9be028fba82b037f/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerT.cs#L22) `Logger<T>` to instantiate the actual logger.

When using the Logging extension in console applications, its recommended still to use the `IServiceCollection`, as this allows you to use the `IServiceCollection` [extension methods](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a057f27e860c1a59aa12e7dd9be028fba82b037f/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32) to register all packages which support this pattern.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging();

// Initialize Autofac
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// Use the Populate method to register services which were registered
// to IServiceCollection
builder.Populate(services);

// Build the final container
IContainer container = builder.Build();
```

This is the recommended approach, as you won't have to think in detail which classes need to registered for libraries which have `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` integration support.

But of course you can also register it manually, but when a change happens to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` library (new dependency added), you won't get it and first have to figure out or dig [into the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L41-L42) to find the error.

```
builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>()
    .As<ILoggerFactory>()
    .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
    .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
    .SingleInstance();
```

All that remains is to register the logger types after the container has been built or before your application starts:

```
var loggerFactory = container.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory.AddConsole()
    .AddSerilog();
```

and in your services inject `ILogger<MyService>` as usual.

Comment: The generic logger needs to be registered using Autofac as such `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>)).SingleInstance();`

Comment: This did not work for me until I added the line that Ruskin commented above. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanOC: Then you likely didn't call `services.AddLogging();` since thats the one which registers the `Logger<T>`/`ILogger<T>` instances

Comment: @Tseng, you are correct. I was able to get it working with your answer alone after spending some more time on it. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to have the correct code. Thank you @Ruskin for the correction.

Comment: How to set LoggerConfiguration?

Comment: @Ruskin, why does the generic logger have to be registered with `SingleInstance()`?

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow Cause you also have singleton services. You can't inject scoped loggers into singleton services obviously. Transient would work though but then each service would get its own instance of it so extra allocations

Comment: I've used this to AddSerilog:


                    builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>()
                        .As<ILoggerFactory>()
                        .OnActivating(args => args.Instance.AddSerilog())
                        .SingleInstance();

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a slightly different approach if you want to register ir manually direct on Autofac:

```
private static void ConfigureLogging(ILoggingBuilder log)
{
    log.ClearProviders();
    log.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error);
    log.AddConsole();
}

private static void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register(handler => LoggerFactory.Create(ConfigureLogging))
        .As<ILoggerFactory>()
        .SingleInstance()
        .AutoActivate();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
        .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
        .SingleInstance();
    // other registrations
}
```

And this on you main startup code:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
ConfigureContainer(containerBuilder);

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
// you can use either the built container or set the serviceProvider onto the library you are using.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Console app Main method

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(optionns => optionns.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString")))
                .AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>))
                .AddLogging() 
                .BuildServiceProvider();

        MyDbContext _context = serviceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();
        var _logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<YourClass>>();
```

Comment: The answer doesn't use AutoFac

Comment: Thanks @ArunSolanki - helpful as I landed here just looking for "adding logging to .net core console"