# Adding serilog to asp.net mvc 5 application on .net framework 4.8

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, autofac, serilog, .net-4.8

Is it possible to add Microsoft.Extensions.Logging with Serilog to asp.net mvc 5 application on .net framework 4.8?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416371), I added this lines of code to Application_Start method

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>()
    .As<ILoggerFactory>()
    .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
    .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
    .SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

But when and how I need to set `LoggerConfiguration`?